# JS (intermediate value).g is not a function intermediate value is not a function when using super operator

Tags: javascript, class, super

I am trying to call super from an anonymous function in JS but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).g is not a function
```

What's wrong with the following code?

```js
class A {
    m() {
      var f = () => {
          super.g();
      };
      return (() => f());
    }

    g() {
        console.log('g');
    }
}

(new A().m())() // Expected console output: g
```

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a complete code and complete error

Comment: The above snippet is complete, if you try to execute it in the Chrome's console, you will see the above mentioned error: `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).g is not a function`.

Comment: why is it `super.g()`, that is the bug.

Comment: Well `super.g` is not a function because your `class A` does not inherit from another class. Did you mean to just call `this.g()`? Why did you use `super`?

Comment: @tonix yes, sorry, I expected `super` to be called from a subclass and automatically evaluated the code without a super-class as incomplete..

Comment: Yeah, I made a really stupid mistake, and confused it with `this`, but thank you anyway. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` extends from `Object`, and `Object.prototype` doesn’t have a `g` method. The anonymous function doesn’t have anything to do with it.

Did you mean:

```js
this.g();
```